# Bug in answerer's identity picture

Tags: bug, design

I know, I have too many badges, but since I'm aiming at 1000+ silver badges, the way the number of badges is shown in answers (for questions I can't tell) is annoying:

[image]

As it stands, it shows 1625 bronze badges less than I actually have. `;-)`

Just for comparison, here's the appearance for a well known StackOverflow user

[image]

Comment: For the purposes of determining the behavior for questions, I think it's imperative that you ask a question on the main site. ;-)

Comment: I would suggest to count 10 bronze as 1 silver and 10 silver as one gold. Like this, egregs count would be 162 g, 8 s, 5 b. 7 digits and three medals seem to fit. (and I would be two bronzes away from gold as I am even too stupid to login 100 days in row...)

Comment: @PaulGessler Well, he should not collect a "First-Question-Bronze" before this bug has been solved...

Comment: @PaulGessler Still haven't found the button to click on.

Comment: You always have the option to sell some of those on the black market meanwhile they work out a solution ;)

Comment: @egreg: You definitely have too many badges ;-) Immediately stop answering ;-)

Comment: Who's this Jon Skeet fellow? Some sort of TeX wannabe, I'd say. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Maybe TeX is the only language he doesn't know.

Comment: @egreg: Oh no! `:)`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi `cron` ;)

Comment: @egreg Donald Knuth wears a "Jon Skeet is my Homeboy" t-shirt to show off at parties.

Comment: It’s even worse on my system, with just about **one** bronze badge left: http://i.stack.imgur.com/amQ3M.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display bug causes number of badges to be shown incorrectly](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/display-bug-causes-number-of-badges-to-be-shown-incorrectly)

Comment: @InPSTrickswetrust -- yes, this is a duplicate, but the response from the "powers" was most unsatisfactory.  i think it's worth another try, and closing this one isn't going to get that result.